# Highmaps with rich information in separate container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I use highmaps with "Rich information on click" in a json format. For this I used a previously existing example. However, there are a few parts that I would like to add.

1. <strike>Separate container in which the extra information (countryChart) is
   displayed instead of a single container in which both the map and
   the extra information are shown</strike> Solution given by ppotaczek
2. <strike>Is it possible to display the total per category if no country is selected. In the example below, this means that in (Countrychart)
   graph, cat1: 14, cat2: 3 and cat3: 15 (Canada, US and India added
   together) are shown.</strike> Solution given by ppotaczek
3. <strike>The flags are not displayed, I cannot figure out why this is.</strike> Solution given by Emad

In this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/Lonr1ae9/56/) I have made a start on the graph hopefully this is a good basis for the extra functionality.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/v6.0.4/samples/data/world-population-history.csv',
  success: function() {
    var jsondata = {
      "data": [{
        "value": "8",
        "code": "in",
        "name": "india",
        "testdata": [{
          "vcount": "3"
        }, {
          "vcount": null
        }, {
          "vcount": "5"
        }]
      }, {
        "value": "15",
        "code": "us",
        "name": "united states",
        "testdata": [{
          "vcount": "9"
        }, {
          "vcount": "2"
        }, {
          "vcount": "4"
        }]
      }, {
        "value": "9",
        "code": "ca",
        "name": "canada",
        "testdata": [{
          "vcount": "2"
        }, {
          "vcount": "1"
        }, {
          "vcount": "6"
        }]
      }]
    }

    var mapChart;
    var countryChart;
    var graphdata = [];
    var graphdataf = [];
    var valuecount;
    var countries = {};

    $.each(jsondata.data, function(i, item) {
      var graphval = [];
      var value = item.value;
      var code = item.code;
      var name = item.name;

      graphval.push(code);
      graphval.push(value);
      graphdata.push(graphval);

      $.each(item.testdata, function(j, itemval) {});
      
      countries[item.code] = {
        name: item.name,
        code3: item.code,
        data: item.testdata
      };
    });

    var data = [];

    for (var code3 in countries) {
      if (countries.hasOwnProperty(code3)) {
        $.each(countries[code3].data, function(j, itemval) {
          //var graphvaldata = [];
          var value = itemval.vcount;
          data.push({
            name: countries[code3].name,
            code3: code3,
            value: value,
          });
        });
      }
    }
    // Wrap point.select to get to the total selected points
    Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Point.prototype, 'select', function(proceed) {
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
      var points = mapChart.getSelectedPoints();
      if (points.length) {
        if (points.length === 1) {
          $('#info #flag').attr('class', 'flag ' + points[0].flag);
          $('#info h2').html(points[0].name);
        } else {
          $('#info #flag').attr('class', 'flag');
          $('#info h2').html('Comparing countries');
        }
        
        $('#info .subheader').html('<h4>Historical population</h4><small><em>Shift + Click on map to compare countries</em></small>');

        if (!countryChart) {
          countryChart = Highcharts.chart('country-chart', {
            chart: {
              height: 250,
              spacingLeft: 0
            },
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            },
            title: {
              text: null
            },
            subtitle: {
              text: null
            },
            xAxis: {
              tickPixelInterval: 50,
              crosshair: true,
              categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
            },
            yAxis: {
              title: null,
              opposite: true
            },
            tooltip: {
              split: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                animation: {
                  duration: 500
                },
                marker: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }
            }
          });
        }
        
        $.each(points, function(i, point) {
          var data,
            dataRaw = countries[point['hc-key']].data;
          if (dataRaw) {
            data = dataRaw.map((p) => parseInt(p.vcount));
          }

          // Update
          if (countryChart.series[i]) {
            countryChart.series[i].update({
              name: this.name,
              data: data,
              type: points.length > 1 ? 'column' : 'column'
            }, false);
          } else {
            countryChart.addSeries({
              name: this.name,
              data: data,
              type: points.length > 1 ? 'column' : 'column'
            }, false);
          }
        });
        
        while (countryChart.series.length > points.length) {
          countryChart.series[countryChart.series.length - 1].remove(false);
        }
        countryChart.redraw();
      } else {
        $('#info #flag').attr('class', '');
        $('#info h2').html('');
        $('#info .subheader').html('');
        if (countryChart) {
          countryChart = countryChart.destroy();
        }
      }
    });
    
    // Initiate the map chart
    mapChart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
      title: {
        text: 'Population history by country'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL/countries/1W?display=default">The World Bank</a>'
      },
      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      },
      colorAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        endOnTick: false,
        startOnTick: false,
        minColor: '#fff',
        maxColor: '#3D1C5C',
        min: 5,
        max: 15,
      },
      tooltip: {
        footerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">(Click for details)</span>'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        data: graphdata,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        joinBy: 'hc-key',
        name: 'Total Play',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        states: {
          select: {
            color: '#a4edba',
            borderColor: 'black',
            dashStyle: 'shortdot'
          }
        }
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

#container {
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
}

#info {
  float: left;
  width: 270px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  border-left: 1px solid silver;
}

#info h2 {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 13pt;
}

#info .f32 .flag {
  vertical-align: bottom !important;
}

#info h4 {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
  #wrapper,
  #container,
  #info {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<!-- Flag sprites service provided by Martijn Lafeber, https://github.com/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/blob/master/LICENSE -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//github.com/downloads/lafeber/world-flags-sprite/flags32.css" />

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <div id="info">
    <span class="f32"><span id="flag"></span></span>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class="subheader">Click countries to view history</div>
    <div id="country-chart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your questions:

1. Both charts are already in separate containers. You can remove the div with `'wrapper'` id to split them so that they do not appear side by side. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8jo7vzty/
2. Yes, for example you can call `select` on some point with an additional argument and sum the data in the wrapped `select` method (depending on that additional argument).

   ```
       if (points.length) {
           ...

           if (arguments[3]) {
               totalData = [];

               Highcharts.objectEach(countries, function(el){
                   el.data.forEach(function(val, i){
                       if (totalData[i]) {
                           totalData[i] += parseInt(val.vcount)
                       } else {
                           totalData[i] = parseInt(val.vcount);
                       }
                   });
               });

               $('#info h2').html('Total data');
               countryChart.series[0].setData(totalData);
               mapChart.series[0].points[0].select(false, false, true);
           }

       } else if (!arguments[3]) {
           $('#info #flag').attr('class', '');
           $('#info h2').html('');
           $('#info .subheader').html('');
           if (countryChart) {
               countryChart = countryChart.destroy();
           }
       }

   ...

   mapChart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', ...);

   mapChart.series[0].points[0].select(true, false, true);
   ```

   **Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mg7x3kje/

   3. The flags are not displayed because your points do not have `flag` property. You can add them in the way as @Emad Dehnavi suggested.

Comment: Hi ppotaczek, I'm very impressed how quickly you managed to do this. Thank you very much for this. The first and third questions are now included in the example. The second question regarding total does not go entirely well yet. If you hover over it you will see at cat1 as a series name India while this should be "Total data". With cat2 there is no value shown if you hover over it. And if you click on India directly from here, cat2 will show a value of 3, while this should be 0. In the other countries there is also no value shown in cat2. Do you have any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: Part of the above problem has been solved by changing a data point containing "null" to "0". However, the question remains whether it is possible to get the serial name "Total Data" instead of "India"? See new modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/dbz024pc/

Comment: Hi @Kees de Jager, You can use `update` method on a series to change the series name. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/go62km78/

Answer (score 2):

I can aswer to your third question : `The flags are not displayed, I cannot figure out why this is.`

The problem is with this line :

```
$('#info #flag').attr('class', 'flag ' + points[0].flag);
```

There is no `flag` property in points object, you can change it to this :

```
$('#info #flag').attr('class', 'flag ' + points[0]["hc-key"]);
```

And you will have the flag now.

https://jsfiddle.net/vq26m8nb/7/

Comment: Thanks Emad, that is at least one of the three questions that has been solved!